# How extract properties from several objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I often find myself doing the below to extract properties from a list of objects just to create an aggregated list. How would this be expressed with LINQ?

```
var totalErrors =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var res in results)
{
    foreach (var err in res.Errors)
    {
        totalErrors
            .Add(err.Key, err.Value);
    }
}

return totalErrors;
```

Comment: That could either be handled with a Contains check or just let it throw an Exception if it's not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` and `ToDictionary` methods:

```
var result = results
     .SelectMany(x => x.Errors) // get all Errors in one sequence
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value); // create new dictionary based on this Enumerable
```

[`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence. And [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx) creates a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` according to a specified key selector function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an aggregation on two levels with `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var totalErrors = results
    .SelectMany(r => r.Errors)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

`SelectMany` "flattens" a collection of collections into a single level, at which point you can apply `ToDictionary` to a flattened list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany :

```
var allErrors = Results.SelectMany( res=>res.Errors );
//foreach( var error in allErrors )...

var dictionary = allErrors.ToDictionary( x=>x.Key, x=> x.Value );
```